CreationExtrasViewModel sample location
When using ViewModel, more exactly the following:
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.7.0'

Functions viewModel are reffering the following sample in the docs:
 /**
 * ...
 * @sample androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.samples.CreationExtrasViewModel
 */
public fun <VM : ViewModel> viewModel(

Where can I find this sample CreationExtrasViewModel? AndroidStudio is only showing it as // Unresolved.
